# Guest middleware on Nuxt Auth not working

Tags: nuxt.js

I have a login page that I would like for logged in users not be able to see. My component is as follow:

```
<template>...</template>
<script lang="ts">
   ...
   @Component({
       layout: 'fullWidth',
       auth: 'guest',
       components: {
         Base,
         BaseAuth,
       }
   })
   export default class Login extends Vue {  ... }
</script>
```

After login if I go to the `/login` route it allows me to view the page. My nuxt configuration is as follow:

```
auth: {
    redirect: {
      login: '/login',
      logout: '/',
      // callback: '/login',
      home: '/'
    },
    strategies: {
      local: {
        endpoints: {
          login: { url: '/auth/login', method: 'post', propertyName: 'token' },
          logout: { url: '/auth/logout', method: 'post' },
          user: { url: '/auth/user', method: 'get', propertyName: 'user' }
        },
      }
    }
  }
```

Is there any other configuration that I should do?

Comment: witch strategy did you used for login? and please add code of your login function

Comment: You can create a function that checks whether the user is already logged in or not. If yes then push the user to home page.

Comment: did you end up finding a solution to this? Same issue here.

Comment: I am also having the same issue and looking for a solution. Anyone has any ideas?

Comment: same issue here, did you found a fix?

Comment: didn't find a solution so far. Gave up on the problem until I actually need to fix it

Answer (score 3):

use this, first register the middleware then use auth.

```js
middleware: 'auth', 
  auth : 'guest',
```

Answer (score 0):

i know it's not a real solution for the module, but what i end up doing was adding a hook on the login page:

```
mounted() {
    if (this.$auth.loggedIn) {
    return this.$router.push('/dashboard')
    }
},
```